# Parquet Errors in PySpark using CDH 5.4 and Spark 1.3.0 with Parquet Table in HIVE

Tags: hive, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I’m running CDH 5.4 using Spark 1.3.0 with Spark on YARN support. 
When I create a simple parquet table in HIVE and then try to perform a transformation or aggregation to it using PySpark it throws this error message to me. Any thoughts? To reproduce the problem do the following…

HIVE:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TestTable_Parquet(
Investment_Id int,
Identifier string,
Package_Id int,
AsOfDate timestamp
) STORED AS PARQUET
;
INSERT INTO TABLE TestTable_Parquet
VALUES (1, "id1", 1, "2015-01-01")
;
```

PySpark:

```
test = sqlCtx.table("testtable_parquet")
test.filter(test.identifier == "id1")
```

Error

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-690105998113> in <module>()
      1 test = sqlCtx.table("testtable_parquet")
----> 2 test.filter(test.identifier == "id1")

/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in filter(self, condition)
    627             jdf = self._jdf.filter(condition)
    628         elif isinstance(condition, Column):
--> 629             jdf = self._jdf.filter(condition._jc)
    630         else:
    631             raise TypeError("condition should be string or Column")

/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
    536         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
    537         return_value = get_return_value(answer, self.gateway_client,
--> 538                 self.target_id, self.name)
    539 
    540         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    298                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    299                     'An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n'.
--> 300                     format(target_id, '.', name), value)
    301             else:
    302                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o34.filter.
: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: resolved attributes identifier missing from investment_id,identifier,package_id,asofdate;
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis.failAnalysis(CheckAnalysis.scala:37)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(CheckAnalysis.scala:93)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(CheckAnalysis.scala:43)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.foreachUp(TreeNode.scala:88)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis.apply(CheckAnalysis.scala:43)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(SQLContext.scala:1069)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.<init>(DataFrame.scala:133)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.logicalPlanToDataFrame(DataFrame.scala:157)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.filter(DataFrame.scala:508)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:379)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:207)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: After a bit of playing, the solution to the problem appears to be running this set conf command first, this is only required when you want Spark to speak to Hive

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of playing, the solution to the problem appears to be running this set conf command first, this is only required when you want Spark to speak to Hive:

```
sqlCtx.setConf("spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreParquet", "false")
```